# Reading from console doesn't stop when I press Enter

Tags: c

I am reading PrenticeHall. [The C Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628) - 2nd Ed.Kernighan,Ritchie.

In this book(pg-20) an example of a program is given which is supposed to print the number of characters that user types in the console window, and here is its code .

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    double nc;
    for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc)
        ;

    printf("%.0f\n", nc);
}
```

But when I run this , and type something in the console, it wont print anything at all, the cursor would keep on blinking .
and this is exactly the way code is written in that book.

I have tried it another way also, but this also didn't work out, same result as that previous code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    long nc;
    nc = 0;
    while (getchar() != EOF)
            ++nc;

    printf("%ld\n", nc);
}
```

any ideas to how to make this thing work ?

P.S.
I am using windows OS. (still)

Comment: How do you end the program? What OS .. do you type ^D or ^Z under Linux/Unix and Windows respectively?

Comment: thanks @hmjd using getchar() != '\n' works with the enter key,

Comment: @SauravTomar, it still works with `EOF`, it just requires some understanding.

Comment: @unkulunkulu its working with EOF also now i know why it wast working earlier.  :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason is that the code tries to read all the input until the end of file. If this program was reading from a file, it would know when it ended, but since it's reading from console, you have to explicitly tell it that the input is over. On Linux you do this by pressing `^D` (Ctrl+D), on Windows `^Z` (Ctrl+Z).

Note that it has to be done at the start of a new line, i.e. after pressing `Enter`, you press `^D` (`^Z` on Win).

> I am reading PrenticeHall. The Ansi C Programming Language - 2nd
>   Ed.Kernighan,Ritchie.

That's a very good book you're reading. It's that good, I guess, it contains the answer to your question.

Answer (score 5):

Both of your programs work, you just need to enter `EOF` as I indicated in the first comment below your question. That is `^D` (Control-D) under Linux and `^Z` (Control-Z) under Windows.

Notice both conditions in the loop are looking for `EOF` not  or some other input to terminate. Once you provide this input the loop is terminated and your count is displayed.

Answer (score 3):

You should stop the input taping `EOF' character (Ctrl+D on GNU/Linux).

Answer (score 2):

My compiler (GCC 4.4) quibbles over the code you have posted.  This eliminates the quibbling:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int nc;
    for (nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; ++nc)
        ;
    printf("%d\n", nc);
    return 0;
}
```

Other answers are right, though:  you must end your keyboard input with Ctrl-D or -Z.

I am not sure why Kernighan and Ritchie have used the `double` in this context, incidentally.